# is there any distinction between following code blocks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class

```js
let x = new (class {
  firstName;
  lastName;
  constructor(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
})("John", "Doe");
```

and

```
class Student{
    firstName; lastName;
    constructor(firstName, lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

let y = new Student("a", "bomb");
```

I know `typeof class` is just a function, and first one is nothing but a self executing function, but what is the difference between them ? how the resulting objects, x and y, will be different, or they wont ?

Comment: The first one creates a new anonymous class every time you execute it, but you can reuse the named `Student` class to create multiple instances.

Comment: thats quite obvious, so there is no differnece between them other than that ?

Answer (score 0):

The first one creates a class with no name and also not assigned to a variable, and then creates an instance.

The second one creates a class with a name `Student` and is assigned to a variable named `Student`. Then, an instance is created.

With both, you can create more instances of the class using `x.constructor` and `y.constructor`, respecitively, though with the second you have the added benefit of having a that constructor already assigned to a variable.

```js
const x = new (class {
  firstName;
  lastName;
  constructor(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
})("John", "Doe");

class Student{
    firstName; lastName;
    constructor(firstName, lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

y = new Student("a", "bomb");

console.log(x.constructor);
console.log(y.constructor);
console.log(Student, Student === y.constructor);

const z = new x.constructor("John", "Cena");

console.log(z);
console.log(z instanceof x.constructor, z instanceof y.constructor);
```